# \xspace doesn't add whitespace before quotes if they are active

Tags: spacing, punctuation, csquotes, xspace

I'm trying to get `\xspace` to add a whitespace before “ if it is an auto quote using `csquotes`. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{xspace}


\MakeAutoQuote{(}{)}

\def\test{test\xspace}

\begin{document}

Hello, \test (after command.)

\end{document}
```

It doesn't do what I want, no matter how hard I try... what am I missing?

EDIT: more info: in the meantime I figured that even this

```
\def\qq{\csq@oqopen}
Hello, \test \qq after command)
```

will not work. Something is going on here that makes `\xspace` think it must not add a space. But I am lost as to why.

Comment: also beware of the white space before `test` in your example

Comment: yes, thanks! But that is only because I left the `\ExplSyntaxOn` out in the too-minimal-WE :)

Answer (score 5):

use `\AtBeginDocument{\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}}`

Comment: wow, thanks, that works flawlessly! Any explanation as to why? I am asking because the xspace documentation claims the opposite: first make the character active, then add it to an exception or remove it.

Comment: the quotes are not active in the preamble

Comment: yes; but that confirms the opposite of the documentation and makes it even less clear to me... I cannot use `\MakeAutoQuote` *anywhere* in the preamble, only with `\AtBeginDocument` does it work. So there must be something else in `\AtBeginDocument`, too, after which `\MakeAutoQuote` has to be executed, right?

Comment: Oh oh, I just discovered that this solution breaks nesting, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157278/atbegindocument-breaks-csquotes-nesting-or-xspace-wont-add-space

Comment: Hours of debugging later I know a little bit more: `\AtBeginDocument` does not enable the quotes, that is why `\xspace` seems to work in the above example (“ is a quote by default). One has to additionally use `\EnableQuotes` to make them active, but then the space is gone again. I'll update the MWE and unaccept this answer.