# \AtBeginDocument breaks csquotes nesting - or \xspace won't add space

Tags: spacing, punctuation, csquotes, xspace

A couple of months ago, I asked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145963/xspace-doesnt-add-whitespace-before-quotes-if-they-are-active) question because `xspace` wasn't adding whitespace before an active quote. The apparent solution was to add `\AtBeginDocument`. However, this breaks `csquotes` nesting as I just found out:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[log-functions=false]{expl3}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}

\usepackage{luatextra}

\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}


\AtBeginDocument{        % comment this for the nesting to work
    \MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \test {} {
    test\xspace
}

\begin{document}

Hello, \test “after command, with just an “inner quote,” which \emph{should} be automatic.”

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to somehow get both to work? The inner quotes switching to single quotes automatically AND the space after the command?

Comment: oh oh.... no answer to this yet? If this is a bug, where would be the correct place to report it?

Comment: as I mentioned in the linked question, the problem is not that nesting doesn't work, but the problem is that `\xspace` really doesn't add a space before `\csq@oqopen`. In the light of that, this question could either be considered invalid or a duplicate of my original question.